# Making a compliment: how to say "this dress suits your eyes"?

Tags: phrase-request

How to say, that some dress matches with person's eyes. I would think of this:

> This dress suits your eyes.

But haven't found such a phrase while searhing the Internet. Please, advise.

Comment: Typically we say "That dress really *brings out* your eyes".

Comment: We use *suits* when talking about the person, but I would use it more  for a man: "That tie (or those pants) really suits *you*." Surely, there are better ways to compliment a woman's appearance.

Answer (score 4):

> That dress really brings out the colour of your eyes.
>
> That dress really complements your eyes.
>
> That dress suits you down to the ground and really makes your eyes shine.

The first one is perhaps the most typical. I was just riffing on the others.

Comment: Okay, I don't even know what *riffing* means here. All I know is that it is a verb that guitar players use.

Comment: _Riffing_ means creatively expanding on a theme with variations - whether in music or in discussion.  I often hear it used to mean "start with an idea and come up with interesting variations or elaborations," but I am a musician and spend a lot of time with musicians, so it may be jargon specific to that crowd.